# Bad practice to modify data by importing parent component?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have my `TenantsComponent` which has data like an array of objects called `tenant` (what a tenant is, is not important).

If for example I want to modify this data in another component called let's say `TenantEditComponent`, is it bad to import the component `TenantsComponent` in the `TenantEditComponent` and modify data like this ?

```
import TenantsComponent from ....;

@Component({
  selector: 'tenant-edit',
  templateUrl: './tenant.edit.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tenant.edit.css']
})

export class TenantEditComponent {

   constructor(public TenantsComponent: TenantsComponent) {

   }

   .
   .
   .

   aFunctionToModifyDataOfTenantsComponent() {
    this.TenantsComponent.tenants[0] = ...;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's generally bad practice to import a component and change it's data explicitly.

There are two better options that I can think of.

Option One: Pass the data down into a child component via `Input()` and mutate it in the child. see [Angular Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Option Two: Use a service as your source of truth, and then you can pass the data into any other component to either view or mutate. Since you'll have a single source of truth, the changes would be reflected throughout the data's use. see [Example of State Management](https://blog.nrwl.io/managing-state-in-angular-applications-22b75ef5625f)